Union 32-bit (u)integer synthesis
In XC16 (for the 16-bit dspic33E***MU8xx and MC family) I use union QEICounter and similar unions to convert two 16-bit words (e.g. read from UDP/serial) to 32-bit int32_t or ulong, which is defined like this:
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int  loWord;           // Counter high word
        unsigned int  hiWord;           // Counter low word
    }f;                             // field access
    unsigned int      w[2];         // 16 bits access
    unsigned long      l;           // 32 bits access   
}qeiCounter;

I noticed that sometimes the compiler apparently doesn't link the w field writes to the l read with repeated usage. I tried declaring the union variable with volatile, and that apparently does not solve it either.
Any idea how to properly do this? I adopted the union trick from older Microchip libraries (plib,MLA)
I'm still in transition from xc16 to xcdsc, so anything that works on both would be great.

This family of compilers (MPLAB + spawn offs) has a notoriously bad reputation. It is quite likely that your problem is caused by compiler bugs or compiler non-conformance. Although make sure you aren't compiling as C++ where code like this invokes undefined behavior.

What exactly do you mean by "doesn't link the w field writes to the l read with repeated usage"? How do you access that variable? What incorrect behaviour do you observe? What compiler do you use?

@GerhardH: In some cases I write to .w and then read from .l , I get an old value. I assume it simply optimizes away the write as a value that is written but not read back (at the free -O1).

Lundin: xc16 and xcdsc are based on resp.  gcc 4 and 8 if I understood correctly.

In some cases I write to .w and then read from .l , I get an old value While your description is valuable, please post the code that you are using. How do you write to w, how do you write to l, how do you get the value, ho wdo you compare it? I assume it simply optimizes so check it, don't assume. List the resulting assembly code from the compilation and follow the instructions and check if the memory is re-read or is hardcoded. | Also, I agree with above, my experience with MPLAB was bad. It was some time ago, maybe newer compilers are better.

@KamilCuk it should no optimize it. If it does then it is the compiler bug

please show us the code where the write / read problem appears.

Please do not describe what you do, but show it. Show the code, the compiled assembler and an example where it does not work.

Replication requires hardware that I only have sporadically and xc16's disassembly of optimised builds is not in order of address. I had hoped somebody would recognise this, and have an attribute to prevent it. Anyway, I'll see what i can do, but it might take a while.

@Marco van de Voort, Curious, for this task why use unsigned int, unsigned long instead of uint16_t, uint32_t since the goal is "convert two 16-bit words to 32-bit"?

Probably historical reasons. The codebase has some C30 origins ( MLA) , which is even more ancient than XC16's gcc4 origins.

Based on chux's comment, I'd use uint16_t et. al. What is sizeof(unsigned int)? I assume 2 for xc16 but a different setup might use 4. I'd double check this.

xcdsc vs xc16-dsc?

xc-dsc which seems to be a new port of gcc, not directly related to xc16.  Most notably it generates more warnings. Unsigned int is 16-bit, and I don't expect it to change, these motor control firmwares are pretty architecture dependent, so portability is not that big a concern. I can't change all types, since some are in a external library (plib)
